# Solving a special rational equation on a very small interval

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, numerical-calculus, error-propagation

I need to solve the following equation (for $x$):
\begin{equation} 
\mathcal f(x):=\sum_{i=1}^n b_i \left( \frac{a_i}{1+b_i x}\right)^2-\phi=0, \quad \text{with} \quad -1/b_1< x \le 0.
\end{equation}
Assume that the equation has at least one solution in $(-1/b_1,0]$ and $b_1\ge b_2\dots\ge b_n>0$. In practice, $b_1$ can be very large, so that the interval of interest $(-1/b_1,0]$ can be very small. Therefore, numerical issues can happen (I think because $1/(1+b_1x)$ can blow up, at least when a numerical method captures a solution that is very close to $-1/b_1$). What is the best practical idea to find a solution of $f(x)=0$ that falls into $(-1/b_1,0]$?

By the way, I am currently using the bisection method and $b_1$ is around 1000 for example. The quantity $n$ could be up to 50 in my case. Further, such an equation must be solved iteratively in my algorithm for different values of $ a_i$'s for $i\in [n]$.
Thank you very much in advance for your time and help.

Comment: Is it known that each $b_i$ is positive?

Comment: You will improve things slightly by rescaling to define everything in terms of $y=b_1 x$, in which case you have $g(y)=\sum_{i=1}^n b_i \frac{a_i^2}{(1+(b_i)/b_1 y)^2} - \phi = 0$. Having done that, the case of a solution very close to $y=-1$ really needs its own rescaling to be checked.

Comment: @hardmath yes $b_i$'s are all positive.

Comment: @Ian thank you so much for the suggestion. I am considering rescaling as a possible remedy but for now, I hope there is something better that can be done.

Comment: Anything better will always start with rescaling.

Comment: @Ian then why not have $y=\alpha b_1x$, where $\alpha$ hopefully helps the numerical solver, let's say 1000.

Comment: What you want is for the range of the variable of interest to be basically $[0,1]$, this plays the best with floating point arithmetic.

Comment: @Ian thank you very much for this important note. I appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry, rather than $[0,1]$ I should say more like $[1,10]$ or so. Confined to one order of magnitude, ideally.

Comment: Bisection is a good starting place, to get a robust interval isolating the unique root.  The function $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing on $(-1/b_1, 0]$ and smooth, so once the root is well isolated (e.g. after a couple of bisection steps), many higher-order convergence methods can be used to give an accurate root.  The Question would be improved by adding such details as how many times the equation has to be solved, how big the index of summation $n$ is, and how much accuracy is needed.

Comment: Thank you very much @hardmath, this is very helpful. My conclusion from the comments is to first transfer the equation to the interval [1,10], next do some bisection steps, and finally use a higher-order method to capture the solution, which is unique.

Comment: @hardmath that would be fantastic. Thank you. It actually does have an interpretation. The solution $x^*$ of the equation is the Lagrangian multiplier of an optimization problem, which is nonconvex. So, the fact that is unique, is very interesting itself.

Comment: @hardmath Since you have mentioned here, I am still waiting for your response to this question. After that, I would be able to accept an answer. More than that I would love to learn your angle on the problem. Please kindly let me know if you will or will not post an answer. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Have a look at my second answer : it is quite important. By the way, if my answers satisfy your needs, may be, you could accept one of them (clicking the gree arrow). Cheers :-)

Answer (score 2):

As said in comments, let $x=\frac y{b_1}$ and $c_i=\frac {b_i}{b_1}$ to make
$$\sum_{i=1}^n b_i \left( \frac{a_i}{1+b_i x}\right)^2=b_1\Bigg[\frac{a_1^2}{(1+y)^2}+\sum_{i=2}^n \frac{ a_i^2\, c_i}{(1+ c_i\,y)^2}\Bigg]$$ Now, to get rid of the vertical asymptote at $y=-1$, we shall muliply everything by $(1+y)^2$ and consider the function

$$g(y)=b_1\Bigg[{a_1^2}+{(1+y)^2}\sum_{i=2}^n \frac{ a_i^2\, c_i}{(1+ c_i\,y)^2}\Bigg]-\phi(1+y)^2$$ for which
$$g(0)=-\phi+b_1 \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2\qquad \qquad g(-1)=b_1\,a_1^2 >0 \qquad \qquad g'(-1)=0$$ $$g''(-1)=-2\phi+2b_1 \sum_{i=2}^n \frac { a_i^2\, c_i } {(1-c_i)^2 }$$

Assuming $g(0)<0$, using Taylor around $y=-1$, we  have
$$g(y)=g(-1)+\frac 12 g''(-1) (y+1)^2+ O\left((y+1)^3\right)$$ and then a first estimate
$$y_0=-1 +\sqrt {-\frac {b_1 a_1^2} {g''(-1)}}$$

Let us try using $n=5$, $b_i=10^{5-i}$, $a_i=p_{i+5}^2$ and $\phi=12345678987654321$. This gives as an estimate
$$y_0=-1+\sqrt{\frac{175914852251400405000}{15208068862859378242920969041} }\sim -0.999892$$
while the exact solution, obtained using Newton method is $-0.999848$

Starting with this guess, Newton iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & y_n \\
 0 & \color{red}{-0.99989}244905795162394 \\
 1 & \color{red}{-0.9998}3867358692746307 \\
 2 & \color{red}{-0.999847}63616543148912 \\
 3 & \color{red}{-0.999847899}77068160754 \\
 4 & \color{red}{-0.999847899999109}03399 \\
 5 & \color{red}{-0.99984789999910920552}
\end{array}
\right)$$

Very immodestly, let me precise that this method bears my name.

**Edit**

If you are coding, for a complete safety,  combine bisection and Newton methods . If you go to [this place](http://astronu.jinr.ru/wiki/images/8/8c/NumericalRecipesinF77.pdf), on page $359$, you will find subroutine **RTSAFE** ([here](http://iop.vast.ac.vn/%7Envthanh/cours/numerical_methods/code/CH2_newton_BS.f) and [here](http://adh.usace.army.mil/svn/adh/PT123/trunk/src/util/rtsafe.f)) which does exactly that. It is very robust.

I apologize for giving you a reference to Fortran coding. If you can access the books of Numerical Recipes, you will find the equivalent in C and C++.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is really great.

Comment: I appreciate very much the edit and the references therein, even though I could only see the book. I am using Python and do not know Fortran. But I am hoping to get the idea of this method and code it personally.

Comment: *brentq* could be a good solution.

Comment: I would like to duplicate your example.  Check that this is your parameter set:$$ b_1 = 10^4, b_2 = 10^3, b_3 = 10^2, b_4 = 10, b_5 = 1 $$
 
 $$ a_1 = 13^2, a_2 = 17^2, a_3 = 19^2, a_4 = 23^2, a_5 = 29^2 $$
$$ \phi = 12345678987654321 $$

Answer (score 2):

*I prefer to add a second answer for some crucial points.*

The solution you are looking for is **not** in the range $-\frac 1{b_1} < x <0$ but in the range $$\color{red}{-\frac 1{b_1}+\epsilon \leq x \leq-\frac 1{b_2}-\epsilon}$$ $\epsilon$ being at the level of machine accuracy. So, if your search method use bounds, these are the ones to be used.

Moreover, in this range, there are **two** possible solutions for $x$ since
$$\lim_{x\to {-\frac{1}{b_1}}+\epsilon}  \, f(x) = +\infty \qquad \text{and} \qquad \lim_{x\to {-\frac{1}{b_2}}-\epsilon}  \, f(x)= +\infty$$but, depending on the value of $\phi$, **no** root is also possible as well as a double root.

Reusing the example worked in my previous answer, if $\phi < 2.57\times 10^8$, there is no solution.

Using $\phi=10^{10}$, the roots are $-9.085\times 10^{-4}$ and $-1.170\times 10^{-4}$ each of them being close to the bounds.

So, considering before any rescaling
$$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n b_i \left( \frac{a_i}{1+b_i x}\right)^2- \phi$$ we should consider
$$g(x)=(1+b_1x)^2(1+b_2x)^2\sum_{i=1}^n b_i \left( \frac{a_i}{1+b_i x}\right)^2- \phi(1+b_1x)^2(1+b_2x)^2$$ that is to say
$$g(x)=a_1^2b_1(1+b_2x)^2+a_2^2b_2(1+b_1x)^2+(1+b_1x)^2(1+b_2x)^2\sum_{i=3}^n b_i \left( \frac{a_i}{1+b_i x}\right)^2-\phi(1+b_1x)^2(1+b_2x)^2$$

So, working around $x=-\frac{1}{b_1}$, we have
$$g\left(-\frac{1}{b_1}\right)=a_1^2 b_1 \left(1-\frac{b_2}{b_1}\right)^2$$
$$g'\left(-\frac{1}{b_1}\right)=2 a_1^2 b_1 b_2 \left(1-\frac{b_2}{b_1}\right)$$
$$g''\left(-\frac{1}{b_1}\right)=2 b_1 b_2 \left(a_1^2 b_2+a_2^2 b_1\right)-2 b_1^2 \left(1-\frac{b_2}{b_1}\right)^2 \phi+$$
$$2 b_1^2 \left(1-\frac{b_2}{b_1}\right)^2\sum_{i=3}^n \frac{a_i^2 b_i}{\left(1-\frac{b_i}{b_1}\right)^2}$$

Now, from these informations, build the parabola
$$h(x)=A+Bx+Cx^2$$
$$C=\frac 12 g''\left(-\frac{1}{b_1}\right)\qquad B=g'\left(-\frac{1}{b_1}\right)+\frac{2C}{b_1}\qquad A=g\left(-\frac{1}{b_1}\right)+\frac{B}{b_1}-\frac{C}{b_1^2}$$ Solve the quadratic $h(x)=0$ and keep the largest root as the approximate solution.

Applied to the worked example, this would give
$$x_0=-0.9998478974\times 10^{-4}$$ while the exact solution is
$$x=−0.9998479000\times 10^{-4}$$

**Update**

In the previous edit, there were $b_1$ and $b_2$ missing as mutliplying factors in the expansion of $g(x)$ but all the remaining was correct.

To allow test with the conditions $n=5$, $b_i=10^{5-i}$, $a_i=p_{i+5}^2$ and $\phi=10^k$, I produced some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
k & \text{estimation} & \text{solution} \\
 10 & -8.26703656651674 \times 10^{-5} & -8.30010445244925 \times 10^{-5} \\
 11 & -9.46205809895313 \times 10^{-5} & -9.46525763471424 \times 10^{-5} \\
 12 & -9.83067188617129 \times 10^{-5} & -9.83098989883711 \times 10^{-5} \\
 13 & -9.94652543341715 \times 10^{-5} & -9.94655718742864 \times 10^{-5} \\
 14 & -9.98309681582244 \times 10^{-5} & -9.98309998987002 \times 10^{-5} \\
 15 & -9.99465543307055 \times 10^{-5} & -9.99465575043391 \times 10^{-5} \\
 16 & -9.99830996825483 \times 10^{-5} & -9.99830999998987 \times 10^{-5} \\
 17 & -9.99946557190165 \times 10^{-5} & -9.99946557507511 \times 10^{-5} \\
 18 & -9.99983099968264 \times 10^{-5} & -9.99983099999999 \times 10^{-5} \\
 19 & -9.99994655747581 \times 10^{-5} & -9.99994655750754 \times 10^{-5} \\
 20 & -9.99998309999683 \times 10^{-5} & -9.99998310000000
\times 10^{-5}
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

If we are sure that $x$ will be very close to $-\frac 1{b_1}$, then, we can write $x= -\frac 1{b_1}+\epsilon$ and expand $f(x)$ as a series around $\epsilon=0$.

Defining
$$u_i=\frac{a_i^2 b(i)}{(1+ b_ix)^2}$$ we have
$$u_1=\frac{a_1^2}{b_1 \epsilon ^2}$$ and, for $i>1$,
$$u_i=b_1^2\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k (k+1)\frac{a_i^2\, b_1^{k}\, b_i^{k+1} } {(b_1-b_i)^{k+2} }\epsilon^k$$ Neglecting the positive powers of $\epsilon$ then leads to the approximate equation
$$\frac{a_1^2}{b_1 \epsilon ^2}+b_1^2 \sum _{i=2}^n \frac{a_i^2 b_i}{(b_1-b_i)^2}=\phi$$

This would  give as a first approximation
$$ x=-\frac 1{b_1}+\frac{a_1}{\sqrt{b_1}}\left(\phi -b_1^2 \sum _{i=2}^n \frac{a_i^2 b_i}{(b_1-b_i)^2}\right)^{-\frac 12} $$

Using it for the above conditions, for $\phi=10^{10}$ this gives  $x=--8.2997747\times 10^{-5}$ and for $\phi=10^{20}$ this gives $x=-9.9999831\times 10^{-5}$; this is much better than the parabolic approximation.

Comment: Thank you for your answers again but I am not still sure why you are claiming that my solution is in this interval, which has a typo for sure as $b_1\ge b_2>0$. I think you mean: $[-1/b_2+\epsilon, -1/b_1-\epsilon]$. Again, in my case, we know $f(0)<0$.

Comment: By the way, could you explain how do you construct the parabola? and even the series in the edit? Any hint would be appreciated! thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The current framing of the Question suggests that the $b_i$'s are fixed but the problem (root-finding) will need to be solved repeatedly for varying coefficient's $a_i$.  My remarks are intended to help with the selection of an initial approximation of the root, to be improved iteratively.

Note that the problem specifies only that the $b_i$'s are ordered by *weak inequalities*:

$$ b_1 \ge b_2 \ge b_3 \ge \ldots \ge b_n $$

Unless the intention is vary those $b_i$'s, we can eliminate *a priori* consecutive terms with equal $b_i$'s (by lumping them together) in the summation that defines $f(x)$:

$$ f(x) := \sum_{i=1}^n b_i \left( \frac{a_i}{1+b_i x} \right)^2  - \phi $$

So let's assume the $b_i$'s are distinct, although to be sure there is no requirement that they are widely spaced.

Then all the terms in the summation are continuous and strictly decreasing on the interval $(-1/b_1,0]$ in which the root is sought, and only the first term fails to be continuous at left hand endpoint $x=-1/b_1$ because the first term tends to $+\infty$ there.

It follows that any root $f(r) = 0$ with $r\in (-1/b_1,0]$ is unique, and such a root exists if and only if $f(0) \le 0$.  The case $f(0)=0$ is easily checked as it amounts to $\sum a_i^2 b_i = \phi$, so we assume hereafter that the check shows $f(0) \lt 0$.

Locating $r$ is striking the right balance between the contributions of the first term, which are "potentially" unbounded, and the contributions of the rest of the summands, which are at most a finite value we can directly evaluate at $x=-1/b_1$.

My suggestion is that we evaluate those terms:

$$ g(x) := \sum_{i=2}^n \frac{a_i^2 b_i}{(1 + b_i x)^2} $$

at two points and use linear interpolation to approximate their sum in between.  Since those terms are concave up (a convex function), that linear interpolation is consistently an overestimate of their true contribution.

Initially we would evaluate $g(x)$ at the two points $x=-1/b_1$ and $x=0$.  Then we would solve the simpler rational equation (as equivalent to a cubic):

$$ \frac{a_1^2 b_1}{(1 + b_1 x)^2} + b_1(g(0) - g(-1/b_1)) x + g(0) = \phi $$

The solution $r_1$ of this equation will yield $f(r_1) \lt 0$ because of the error introduced by linear interpolation.  Therefore $r_1 \gt r$ overestimates the actual root.

We can then repeat this procedure, replacing evaluation of $g$ at the upper endpoint $x=0$ with evaluation at new upper endpoint $x=r_1$.  The attraction of this method is that it conservatively approaches the actual root from above, and therefore does not risk passing the singularity at $x = -1/b_1$.

Comment: Thank you for this fantastic approach. Shouldn't it be $(1+b_1x)^2$ in the bottom of the given equation? and therefore, you get a cubic polynomial to solve? And, in case we have a nonunique real solution, which one should be picked? I am guessing the smallest one.

Comment: You are correct; it is a cubic.  I think the solution turns out to be unique in the range $(-1/b_1,0]$.  I think applying this to Claude's example will turn up some implementation details.

Comment: Take care : the solution is **not** between $-1/b_1$ and $0$ but between $-1/b_1$ and $-1/b_2$ since there are $n$ vertical asymptotes. Over the last 30 years, I published quite many papers for this type of equations (search for *"my_name + Rachford-Rice"* and  *"my_name + Underwood"*. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici:  The problem asks for a root $f(r) = 0$ with $r$ between $-1/b_1$ and $0$.  Such a root exists iff $f(0)\le 0$. The function $f(x)$ has $n$ double polls, but there may or may not be a root between $-1/b_1$ and $-1/b_2$.

Comment: Between two consecutives $-1/b_ii$, we have a U shape curve going through a minimum and we do not know the minimum value of it. If $f_{min}<0,we have two roots in the interval. In fact, we face the problem of a polynomial fo degree $2n$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Nevertheless, the problem specifically calls for a root in $(-1/b_1,0]$, so while $f$ may or may not have a root in $(-1/b_2,-1/b_1)$, my Answer concerns when the solution called for in the Question exists.

Comment: If it helps, I could show that $f(0)<0$ in my case. So, we do have a solution in $(-1/b_1,0)$.